# how to find two right-inverse functions of a function

Tags: functions, inverse, function-and-relation-composition

i am stuck in this problem. i need to find two right-inverse functions of this function:

$h: \Bbb N_0\times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N, (m,n)\mapsto m+n$.

i know that the function h' is a right inverse of a function h if and only if:

$h  \circ h' = m+n$.

how can i say this in mathematical way and as for the h function given above?  i did this:

$h': \Bbb N->\Bbb N_0\times\Bbb N, m+n\mapsto (m,n)$.
  $h \circ h' = h(h'(m+n))=m+n$

but now from here, i dont know how to finish the proof and how to show another right-inverse function of h

thanks for help in advance

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: Note that just writing $h'(m+n)=(m,n)$ doesn't make it a well-defined function (and that is why you struggle to find another one). Say, what is $h'(5)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you point out, $h^{-1}$ maps naturals to pairs $(m, n)$. If you think about what $h^{-1}$ is doing, you'll see that you need to find a pair $(m, n)$, $m \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m+n$ is the function $h^{-1}$'s input. That is, if $h^{-1}(k) = (m, n)$, then $m + n = k$. An easy approach is to fix some $m$ first, then let $n = k - m$. This will work provided $k > m$. We can then handle the remaning cases separately. This gives $h^{-1}(n) = (0, n)$ as a simple example, since $(0, n) \in \mathbb{N}_0 \times \mathbb{N}$. So that gives one right inverse. Another can be given by, for example,

$$h^{-1}(n) = \begin{cases}(1, n-1), & \mbox{if } n > 1\\(0, 1), & \mbox{if } n = 1\end{cases}$$

Can you devise a suitable function for $m = 2$? For $m = 3$?

Comment: wow, thanks, now i understand. 
yeah, for $m=2$, $n$ will remain as free choice, so that i can say: 
$h^-1(2+n)->(2,n)$, right?

Comment: Yes, but you still need to define it for inputs less than or equal to 2.

Answer (score 1):

The notation for $h\circ h'$ as '$m+n$' is not correct mathematically. Though, I think I understand what you were thinking about.

You need the following, $h':\Bbb N\to \Bbb N_0\times\Bbb N$, this maps any natural number to a *pair* of natural numbers (if I understand it right, the first element of this pair can also be zero). And what is needed, is,

> if for an $s\in\Bbb N$, we have $h'(s)=(u,v)$, then $u+v=s$ holds.

Comment: yes, you are right about what i am thinking about. i think, there are more than 2 right-inverse function, right?

Comment: Well, mike4ty4 already gave you infinitely many right inverses (one for each $m$)..

Answer (score -1):

Just to give a little more clarity. For each $m\in \mathbb{N}$, define $g_{m}:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_{0}\times \mathbb{N}$ as
\begin{eqnarray*}
g_{m}(n)=\left \{
\begin{array}{cc}
(m,n-m)&\text{ if } n\geq m\\
(0,n)&\text{ if } n<m
\end{array}\right.
\end{eqnarray*}

Then each $g_{m}$ is a right inverse of $h$.